# ASP.NET reloading Kestrel SSL certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#change-the-defaults-in-code) I'm planning to load a SSL cert for Kestrel like this:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
    {
        var certPath = context.Configuration["CERT_PATH"]; // CERT_PATH would be /path/to/ssl/cert.pem
        listenOptions.ServerCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certPath);
    });
});
```

During the runtime of the app the certificate file could be updated (renewed). The file would change, not the path. How would Kestrel get the new cert? Is there some way to periodically reload the used `ServerCertificate` etc? The app will be running in a Docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor your certificate and reload it in the Changed event when changes occur.

> [ServerCertificateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.https.httpsconnectionadapteroptions.servercertificateselector?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is a delegate that is called on every HTTPS connection and returns the certificate used for that connection. When your FileSystemWatcher detects changes to the certificate file, it loads the new certificate and updates the certificate returned by the delegate. This way, even established connections will use the new certificate when their next HTTPS handshake occurs

*Please check the test result first.*

[image]

**My sample Code**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            string certPath = @"C:/certificate.crt";
            string certKeyPath = @"C:/private.key"; ;

            X509Certificate2 currentCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certPath, certKeyPath);

            // Configure Kestrel to use the certificate
            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (context, name) => currentCertificate;
                });
            });
            
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Set up the file watcher
            var certFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetDirectoryName(certPath))
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
                Filter = Path.GetFileName(certPath)
            };
            //var init = CertificateHelper.ExportToPem(currentCertificate);
            certFileWatcher.Changed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //var currentCertificateTxt = CertificateHelper.ExportToPem(currentCertificate);
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate file changed. Reloading...");

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                // Load the new certificate
                currentCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certKeyPath);
                //currentCertificateTxt = CertificateHelper.ExportToPem(currentCertificate);
            };

            certFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())), 
                RequestPath = "" 
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

           

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```